# How to do attribute matching in (thinking) sphinx extended2 mode?

Tags: ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have this expression which is working as expected in Thinking Sphinx:

```
Customer.search :with => {:signer_id => 23}
```

but I need to write an expression with OR of some attributes, like signer_id is 23 or admin_level is 42, so I moved to extended match mode and wrote this:

```
Customer.search "@signer_id 23", :match_mode => :extended2
```

which according to my understanding of the [Sphinx relevant documentation](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax), it should be equivalent, but it doesn't match anything at all. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? How do I write an extended thinking sphinx expression?

Copied and pasted from the console:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Customer.search(:with => {:signer_id => 23}).count
 => 20 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Customer.search "@signer_id 23", :match_mode => :extended2
 => [] 
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Customer.search("@signer_id 23", :match_mode => :extended2).count
 => 0
```

**Update:** fixed the id (32 -> 23).

Answer (score 0):

I did this to do matching on fields that I have normalized out.  This reduces the amount of churn in the db by having the same text in the full text search.

Querying: 'pizza | @product_codes (965|1636|1848|2939|4227|5067|5735) | @brand_codes (1485) | @service_codes (2782)

Note as the other answer points out you cannot do properties this way, these have to be indexed fields.

I brute force them out like this:

```
        indexes '(select group_concat(products.id) from business_products inner join products on (products.id = business_products.product_id) where business_id = `businesses`.`id` group by business_id)', :as => :product_codes, :type => :integer
```

Additionally you will need to reduce the number of characters in a word by setting this

```
  min_word_len: 1
```

Otherwise it won't match your 1 and 2 digit number codes.

Comment: I made the same mistake and an math olympic; they couldn't believe such an idiot like me actually won it ;) Anyway, I made the mistake only here, the code was fine and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not spotting the section in the docs that says you can use the `@attribute value` syntax - it's only for fields, not attributes. At least, that's my understanding. Would be fantastic if I'm wrong :)

Comment: What's the difference between fields and attributes?

Comment: Fields are the textual data for your records - ie: all the words that should match against search queries. Attributes are integers, timestamps, booleans, floats to sort and filter results by. Have a read of the Fields and Attributes sections on this page: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/sphinx_basics.html

Comment: @pat sorry for commenting on a two year old thread, but aren't you the author of ThinkingSphinx? That's a mighty humble answer for the guy who wrote the thing!

Comment: Hah, yes Thinking Sphinx is my library. Doesn't mean I know everything about Sphinx though, nor am I always right (just most of the time ;)